# What is a Parse Collection?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm learning Parse (the Javascript flavor) using their [Todo App tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/todo-app-with-javascript). I'm trying to write my first query. In the tutorial, I found this code:

```
var TodoList = Parse.Collection.extend({ ... });
```

I can't find any info about `Parse.Collection` in their [JS Guide](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide) nor their [API docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/).

Can someone shed some light on what a `Parse.Collection` is and when I should use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not seeing anything in the docs because Parse.Collection was removed from the JavaScript SDK in v.1.6.0.

[Downloads Page and JavaScript Changelog](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/wiki/Legacy-Release-Notes)

> SDK no longer contains Backbone-specific behavior. Moving forward, the core SDK will not be tied to any single framework, but we will work with the community to produce up-to-date bindings like Parse+React. The major changes are the removal of Parse.Collection, and allowing Parse.Objects to act as event channels.

In previous versions of the SDK, Parse.Collection was used almost identically to Backbone.Collection, as the Parse SDK was based on Backbone. Things are particularly confusing right now because tutorials on parse.com use pre-1.6.0 versions of the SDK.

Comment: Where does it say that ? What should you use instead?

Comment: @shim, follow the link in my answer, scroll down to the bottom of the JavaScript Changelog and click "see more >>". You will see it in the notes for "v1.6.0 — September 9, 2015".